# pecl install apc isn't working. shtool does not exist

Tags: php, apc, pecl

I am an absolute newbie…didn't learn about SSh till an hour ago and got my first VPS 2 hours ago. Still learning!

So I'm installing MediaWiki and need to add APC extension. But having a lil trouble. Any ideas/tips?

```
[root@www ~]# pecl install apc`
downloading APC-3.1.13.tgz ...
Starting to download APC-3.1.13.tgz (171,591 bytes)
.....................................done: 171,591 bytes
55 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
shtool at '/var/tmp/APC/build/shtool' does not exist or is not executable.
Make sure that the file exists and is executable and then rerun this script.`
```

Comment: can you please post the output of the mount command? Maybe your /var partition have nosuid,noexec set

Answer (score 43):

Remove noexec flag from /var/tmp directory use the following command

```
mount -o remount,exec /var/tmp/
```

You can use the same command to add the noexec flag back

```
mount -o remount,noexec /var/tmp/
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, but on Ubuntu I needed to run `sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp/` and then `sudo mount -o remount,noexec /tmp/`

Comment: See apolinux' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40891414/3102305) for a more appropriate workaround which will also work in environments that do not allow remounting /tmp, e.g. shared hostings or docker container when set to tempfs.

Answer (score 20):

Try this, copied from http://blog.litespeedtech.com/2013/04/05/trouble-shooting-pecl-install-doesnt-work/

> A more appropriate workaround is to point PECL’s `temp_dir` to a
>   partition or path that allows execution:
>
> ```
> mkdir /root/tmp
> pecl config-set temp_dir /root/tmp
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> pear config-set temp_dir /root/tmp
> ```
>
> (There is a known bug where `pecl config-set` does not work but `pear
>   config-set` does. If this is the case for you, simply use the PEAR
>   config command. PECL will use PEAR when doing the install.)
>
> This workaround preserves any security benefit from having /tmp set as
>   noexec, but also allows PECL installs.