# Cannot install MongoDB PHP driver on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to install the MongoDB PHP driver, but I'm getting an unexpected error. When I run: `pecl install mongo` I get this:

> downloading mongo-1.4.5.tgz ...
>
> Starting to download mongo-1.4.5.tgz (141,417 bytes)
>
> ..............................done: 141,417 bytes
>
> 84 source files, building
>
> running: phpize
>
> Configuring for:
>
> PHP Api Version:         20090626
>
> Zend Module Api No:      20090626
>
> Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
>
> shtool at '/tmp/pear/temp/mongo/build/shtool' does not exist or is not executable.
>
> Make sure that the file exists and is executable and then rerun this script.
>
> If the command failed with 'phpize: not found' then you need to install php5-dev
>   package
>
> You can do it by running 'apt-get install php5-dev' as a root user
>
> ERROR: `phpize' failed

when I try to install php5-dev, it says that I already have the latest version, same thing if I run: `apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear`

Thank you.

Comment: Not really a SO error more a super user or server fault I gues.  Also if you're running a debian or redhat based distro you can just do `apt-get install mongo` or `yum install mongo` and it'll do the work for you.  You have 2 errors both because of missing dependancies

Comment: @Dave: the OP was attempting to install the PHP driver, not MongoDB itself. OP: I assume this may be due to PECL unpacking into `/tmp`, which may be mounted with `noexec`. This is answered in more detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17332287/162228). Also, while checking that you have required packages installed, ensure `build-essential` is also in place.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Why are you trying to download the tgz and extract it manually (and a very old one at that) when there is a repository for it. Here are the installation instructions: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

Comment: The OP was asking about installing the PHP driver for MongoDB, not the server itself.